# Getting a random record within blade loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to get a random image within my view, not sure if it is possible the way I intend it to be.  Code example:

```
@foreach ($gallery_albums as $album)
    {{$album->name}}
        @foreach ($album->galleryImages as $images)
            <img src="/galllery/{{$image->name}}"
        @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Within the second foreach, I am pulling through all the images in the album, all I want to do is pull 1 random image, which is what I am not sure how to achieve.

Hopefully, that makes sense, any help is appreciated.

Comment: use `random()` method from collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [random method of the collection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-random)

```
@foreach ($gallery_albums as $album)
    {{$album->name}}
    <img src="/galllery/{{$album->galleryImages->random()->name}}"
@endforeach
```